# Xamarin Form in VS 2015 Community not able to start debug

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, vs-community-edition

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and download latest VS 2015 community to try Xamarin Forms. I try to build the project but it took very long hour to build. It seem like downloading something. After few hour, it success build and in future build it not took so long. The problem now is when I want test the Android project using the simulator, it start the simulator and the simulator keep loading and nothing display. Not sure what going wrong. The simulator I use is Android 4.4 - API level 19. Whats wrong of my project, any setting I miss?

Comment: Either you have malware, don't have enough memory... or something else.

Comment: Have you tried to use another android emulator? like Genymotion? or Xamarin Android Emulator? Have you downloaded the latest Android SDK updates?

Comment: @MarioGalván When I click the start button from VS 2015, it start the Xamarin Android Emulator but keep loading on the emulator and nothing show.  The latest SDK I install is Android 6.0(API 23)

Comment: @DerickLoo You can download genymotion emulator in their webpage and you can choose which device you want to emulate, try to start the emulator with new emulators (you can create as many emulators as you want, Xamarin Android Player has quite a lot, if that does not work try genymotion)